# Why Jsoup div doesn't give "null" if it's null?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have an jsoup code in my android app which I use for checking if there is an div on website, but it keeps me returning "porukeDiv IS NOT NULL" even if it is. Here's the code:

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

            // Now you can, for example, retrieve a div with id="username" here
            Elements porukeDiv = doc.select("div#logovan > a[header-pvtmsg-link]"); //bilo Element
            String porukeText = porukeDiv.text();
            System.out.println("porukeDiv: " + porukeDiv);
            System.out.println("porukeText: " + porukeText);
            if (porukeDiv != null) {
                System.out.println("porukeDiv NOT NULL! ");
                if (porukeText.startsWith("Poruke (")) {
                    loggedin[0] = true;
                    startstopAlarmPoruke();
                }
            }else{
                loggedin[0] = false;
                startstopAlarmPoruke();
                System.out.println("porukeDiv NULL! ");
```

But when it is null, this is information I get in logcat:

```
11-21 06:14:25.092      868-927/com.package.pack I/System.out﹕ porukeDiv:
11-21 06:14:25.092      868-927/com.package.pack I/System.out﹕ porukeText:
11-21 06:14:25.092      868-927/com.package.pack I/System.out﹕ porukeDiv NOT NULL!
```

Why this occurs?

Comment: It's definitelly not null. If it was, `String porukeText = porukeDiv.text();` would throw NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the API doc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select(java.lang.String)), `doc.select(...)` doesn't return `NULL`, but an empty [`Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) collection if nothing is found that matches the selector.

Try testing it this way:

```
if (!porukeDiv.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("porukeDiv NOT Empty! ");
}else{
    System.out.println("porukeDiv Empty! ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object isn't null, it's initialized with empty values.

You could check the porukeDiv and porukeText for "" instead.

use porukeText.equals("") not the '==' operator